# Can I get NugetRestore to work with build.cake on azure devops (TFS)

Tags: c#, azure-devops, nuget, cakebuild

I am trying to extract build tasks from TFS to **cake** scripts so that the build tasks get versioned together with the code. I have managed to create a script which cleans, NuGet-restores, builds, and runs unit tests on my project. It all works fine locally. however, after configuring TFS to run my cake script it keeps failing on following error:

```cs
2019-07-24T11:30:58.0377820Z ##[error]Unable to find version '4.4.3' of package 'System.Data.SqlClient'.
2019-07-24T11:30:58.0385573Z ##[error]Unable to find version '11.0.1' of package 'Newtonsoft.Json'.
2019-07-24T11:30:58.0401542Z ##[error]An error occurred when executing task 'Restore-Nuget-Packages'.
2019-07-24T11:30:58.0449315Z ##[error]Error: One or more errors occurred.
2019-07-24T11:30:58.0450913Z ##[error]  NuGet: Process returned an error (exit code 1).
2019-07-24T11:30:58.0739069Z ##[error]System.Exception: Unexpected exit code 1 returned from tool Cake.exe
```

I tried to change the Cake task settings to use different versions of Nuget and feed urls. Currently, they look like this:

**Nuget Exe Location:** https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe

**Tool Feed Url:** https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

We do have a private nuget host and I have tried modifying the tool feed url. However, from the logs it seems like the feed urls are OK.

Cake output:

```
Feeds used:
2019-07-24T11:30:55.7676783Z   C:\Users\{usr}\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache
2019-07-24T11:30:55.7677002Z   C:\Users\{usr}\.nuget\packages\
2019-07-24T11:30:55.7677066Z   http://{ournugeturl}
2019-07-24T11:30:55.7677233Z   http://{ournugeturl2}
2019-07-24T11:30:55.7677301Z   http://{ournugeturl3}
2019-07-24T11:30:55.7677572Z   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\
```

Other nuget packages are installed, e.g,

```
2019-07-24T11:30:55.7882050Z Restoring NuGet package Autofac.4.8.1.
2019-07-24T11:30:55.9806596Z Adding package 'Autofac.4.8.1' to folder 'd:\w1\3263\s\packages'
```

I even set the verbosity level to Detailed in the Nuget-Restore task, however, I do not manage to find where the problem is.

Snippet from **cake.build**.

```
Task("Restore-Nuget-Packages")
    .IsDependentOn("Clean")
    .Does(() =>
    {
        NuGetRestore(solution, new NuGetRestoreSettings {
            Verbosity = NuGetVerbosity.Detailed,
        });
    });
```

my NuGet.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <solution>
    <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
  </solution>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="privaterepo1" value="http://privatenugetrepo/nuget/NTS" />
    <add key="privaterepo2" value="http://privatenugetrepo/Default" />
    <add key="nugetv3" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
  </activePackageSource>
  <packageRestore>
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />
  </packageRestore>
</configuration>
```

*build.cake*

```
#tool "nuget:?package=xunit.runner.console&version=2.4.1"

var target = Argument("target", "Default");
var configuration = Argument("configuration", "Release");

var solution = "./pathtosolution.sl";

////////////////////////////////////////////////
///// Clean the project packages
////////////////////////////////////////////////
Task("Clean")
    .Does(() => 
  {
        CleanDirectory("./packages");
    });

////////////////////////////////////////////////
///// Adds private Nuget feed links
////////////////////////////////////////////////
Task("Add-Private-NuGet-Feed")
    .Does(() =>
  {
    string[] sources = {
      "private-src1",
      "private-src2",
      "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json"
      };

    foreach(string feed in sources)
    {
      if (!NuGetHasSource(feed))
      {
        var accessToken = EnvironmentVariable("SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN")
                            ?? throw new Exception("VSTS System Access Token is required to setup Private NuGet Feed");
      Information($"Source {feed} is missing");
      NuGetAddSource($"MyCompany-NuGet {feed}", feed, new NuGetSourcesSettings
      {
        UserName = "VSTS",
        Password = accessToken,
    }
        );
      } else 
      {
        Information($"Source {feed} Exists");
      }
    }

  });

////////////////////////////////////////////////
///// Restores all nuget packages.
////////////////////////////////////////////////
Task("Restore-Nuget-Packages")
  .IsDependentOn("Add-Private-NuGet-Feed")
  .Does(() =>
  {
    var solutions = GetFiles("./**/*.sln");
    // Restore all NuGet packages.
    foreach(var solution in solutions)
    {
      Information(solution);
      Information("Restoring {0}", solution);
      var nugetRestoreSettings = new NuGetRestoreSettings {
    ConfigFile = new FilePath("./NuGet.Config"),
    //MSBuildVersion = NuGetMSBuildVersion.MSBuild15
};
      NuGetRestore(solution, nugetRestoreSettings);
    }
  });

////////////////////////////////////////////////
///// Runs DotNetCoreRestore
////////////////////////////////////////////////
Task("DotNetCoreRestore")
  .Does(() => 
  {
    DotNetCoreRestore(
      solution,
      new DotNetCoreRestoreSettings()
      {});
  });

////////////////////////////////////////////////
///// Runs unit tests.
////////////////////////////////////////////////
Task("xUnit")
  .IsDependentOn("Build")
    .Does(() =>
  {

     var projects = GetFiles("./*.Tests/**/*.Tests.csproj");
    foreach(var project in projects)
    {
      DotNetCoreTest(
      project.FullPath,
      new DotNetCoreTestSettings()
        {
        // Set configuration as passed by command line
        Configuration = configuration
        });
    }
  });

////////////////////////////////////////////////
///// Build
////////////////////////////////////////////////
Task("Build")
  .IsDependentOn("Clean")
  .IsDependentOn("Add-Private-Nuget-Feed")
  .IsDependentOn("DotNetCoreRestore")
  .IsDependentOn("Restore-Nuget-Packages")
  .Does(() =>
  {
    MSBuild(solution, new MSBuildSettings {
        ToolVersion = MSBuildToolVersion.VS2017});
  });

////////////////////////////////////////////////
///// The main task.
////////////////////////////////////////////////
Task("Default")
  .IsDependentOn("xUnit");

RunTarget(target);
```

Comment: If the Tool Feed Url: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json included in your feeds used? You can try to configure the `nuget.config` https://blog.ostebaronen.dk/2017/11/cake-restore-nuget-from-private-feed.html or check if NuGet source exists:https://kevsoft.net/2018/08/06/configuring-private-vsts-nuget-feeds-with-cake.html. If it mot resolve your issue, try to share your `nuget.config`.

Comment: The links you posted were a good read, and I followed a few of the suggestions to try to see if it solves my problem, however, no luck. I edited my post so you can see my nuget.config. In TFS I see that the feeds are being used. The project is in the "old" csproj format may this have any impact? I tried to create a small project (with new csproj format) and required the newtonsoft.json, VSTS successfully installed it...

Comment: Thanks for you reply. How about your build definition? If you are using `DotNetCoreBuild`?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT - I added the build.cake file above in the question. Thank you for you help!

Comment: By replacing the Cake task in TFS with a Powershell Script invoking  *build.ps1* on the build server resolved my problem.

Comment: Great! I am glad to hear that you have resolved your issue. You could convert your workaround in your question as answer before you get the best solution. So it could help other community members who get the same issues and find the answer more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**

By replacing the **Cake** task in TFS with a Powershell Script invoking  **build.ps1** on the build server resolved my problem.
[image: TFS screenshot where CAKE is disabled and replaced with powershell script.]